# Etherem connection with Decentralized application

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I Need to setup ethereum for thesis work and I need to use smart contract too. The Etereum should be  private and I can make changes, Please give me step by step solution

Comment: Hi Nirjhor. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please google for ethereum-setup-tutorial, that best matches your preferences and experience. Set up your environment. If you'll encounter an obstacle, try to solve it, and if you're stuck with it, please ask it here. Everyone will be willing to help you!

Comment: Dear I want to setup a private Ethereum which will communicate with IPFS and Dapp. Will I be able to do that??? And if you have any article regarding that please share with me. I am a very beginner level and I am in a problem with my thesis work